# Selector to get element inside div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following code:

```
<div class="div1">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <div class="whatevername1" style="color:blue;">
            text1...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div2">
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <div class="whatevername2" style="color:blue;">
            text1...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to select the class `whatevername` as a child starting from the first div class.

**Edit:**

I don't have class whatevername, could be any name generated dynamically and that's the element that I want to select.

Comment: You don't have a class named "whatevername"...

Comment: Have you had a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ?

Comment: How about changing class name to "whatevername" and making IDs "whatevername1", "whatevername2". This would be hell lot easy & efficient to select

Comment: @ViralPatel how would that change anything?

Comment: @ViralPatel The IDs are unnecessary, since each would be uniquely identified by `.div1 .whatevername` and `.div2 .whatevername`

Comment: I don't have class whatevername, could be any name generated dynamically

Comment: @nickf In his html, the class names are different whatevername1, whatevername2 etc. You need a regex to select such element as mentioned by Adil. It is better to stick one class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.whatevername1')
```

to select the `div`

**UPDATE** To the edit

```
$('.text_wrapper').children('div');
```

if you want to select first you can use `:eq(0)` like this

```
$('.text_wrapper:eq(0)').children('div');
```

Comment: assuming that I have several text_wrapper with the same class name, I would like to access only to the element inside div1

Comment: if you want to access the element inside div1 you can use eq(0) like this ´$('.text_wrapper:eq(0)').children('div');´

Answer (score 1):

To select a class name starts `whatevername`

```
var ele= $('div [class^="whatevername"]')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hbjp9/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.div1').children('.whatevername').[dosomething]
```

To select the `whatevername` inside the `div1`

Answer (score 0):

This selects the contents of both 2 divs:

`$('div > [class^=whatevername']).html()`

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZPU3/